# Why fmap doesn't work for a tuple?

Tags: haskell, tuples, functor

In the below, I tried to use `fmap` on a tuple, but this didn't work, although it worked for a list and `Just 4`:

```
Prelude> fmap (+3) (Just 4)
Just 7
Prelude> fmap (+3) [1,2,3,4]
[4,5,6,7]
Prelude> fmap (+3) (10,11,12,13,14)

<interactive>:38:1: error:
    * Non type-variable argument
        in the constraint: Functor ((,,,,) a b1 c d)
      (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    * When checking the inferred type
        it :: forall a b1 c d b2.
              (Num d, Num c, Num b1, Num a, Num b2, Functor ((,,,,) a b1 c d)) =>
              (a, b1, c, d, b2)
Prelude>
```

Comment: Because a tuple has type `(a, b, c)` (can be generalized), so if you would make it an instance of `Functor`, you can only map a *single* element.

Comment: A question, to help delimiting the scope of the answers: which result did you expect to get from `fmap (+3) (10,11,12,13,14)`, and does that look like what you get from `fmap (+3) (10,11)`?

Comment: A 2-tuple is by the way an instance of `Functor`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Why fmap doesn't work for a [5-]tuple?

Because no one has added the 5-tuple `Functor` instance to *base* yet. If you have a look at [the list of `Functor` instances provided by *base*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.0.0/docs/Data-Functor.html#t:Functor), you will find `Functor ((,) a)`, the instance for pairs, but not the instances for larger tuples, including `Functor ((,,,,) a b c d)`, which is what you'd need here.

The follow up question would of course be: Why has no one added the 5-tuple `Functor` instance to *base* yet? One reason has to do with necessity (or the lack thereof): in practice, pairs show up much more often than larger tuples, and as tuples get larger it becomes harder and harder to justify using them instead of a non-anonymous type suited to one's use case. That being so, the demand for `Functor` instances for larger tuples isn't all that big.

Though you didn't mention which behaviour you expected for `Functor ((,,,,) a b c d)`, it is worth noting that `fmap` for pairs acts only on the second component, and instances for larger tuples would analogously only deal with the last component.

```
GHCi> fmap not (False, True)
(False,False)
```

Two reasons for that are:

1. The types of the components can be different, and so there is no way e.g. `fmap not ("foobar", True)` could possibly change both components.
2. There is no way to flip type constructors when writing instances, and so e.g. there can't be a `Functor` instance for pairs that acts on the first component (unless you use [a newtype wrapper](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bifunctors-5/docs/Data-Bifunctor-Flip.html), but that is besides the point).

While this behaviour might seem surprising, it is entirely reasonable if you think of a pair with type `(a, b)` as a `b` value with an annotation (tag, label, extra stuff -- however you like to call it) of type `a` attached to it. In the cases you'd rather think of it as a pair of two values that can be independently modified, you can resort to the `Bifunctor` class:

```
GHCi> import Data.Bifunctor
GHCi> first reverse ("foobar", True)
("raboof",True)
GHCi> second not ("foobar", True)
("foobar",False)
GHCi> bimap reverse not ("foobar", True)
("raboof",False)
```

(*base* doesn't provide `Trifunctor`, `Tetrafunctor`, and so forth due to lack of need, as discussed at the beginning.)

It is just as reasonable to regard larger tuples in the same manner when it comes to giving them `Functor` instances; and in fact those instances arguably should exist for the sake of consistency. However, some people do strongly dislike the instance for pairs, which has led [proposals to add the instances for other tuples](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2017-January/126026.html) to stall.

P.S.: It is perhaps worth mentioning that one of the (many) use cases of the *lens* library is using things that aren't `Functor`s as functors. That give us a convenient way to see what `Functor` and (if that were a thing) `Pentafunctor` instances would do with a 5-tuple:

```
GHCi> import Control.Lens
GHCi> over _5 (+3) (10,11,12,13,14)
(10,11,12,13,17)
GHCi> over _4 (+3) (10,11,12,13,14)
(10,11,12,16,14)
GHCi> over _3 (+3) (10,11,12,13,14)
(10,11,15,13,14)
GHCi> over _2 (+3) (10,11,12,13,14)
(10,14,12,13,14)
GHCi> over _1 (+3) (10,11,12,13,14)
(13,11,12,13,14)
```

There are even ways to map over all components...

```
GHCi> over both (+3) (13,14)
(16,17)
GHCi> over each (+3) (10,11,12,13,14)
(13,14,15,16,17)
```

... though, unsurprisingly, they demand all components to have the same type:

```
GHCi> over each (+3) (True,11,12,13,14)

<interactive>:9:12: error:
    * No instance for (Num Bool) arising from a use of `+'
    * In the second argument of `over', namely `(+ 3)'
      In the expression: over each (+ 3) (True, 11, 12, 13, 14)
      In an equation for `it':
          it = over each (+ 3) (True, 11, 12, 13, 14)
```

```
GHCi> :set -XPartialTypeSignatures
GHCi> :set -fno-warn-partial-type-signatures
GHCi> :t \f -> over each f :: (_,_,_,_,_) -> _
\f -> over each f :: (_,_,_,_,_) -> _
  :: (w -> b5) -> (w, w, w, w, w) -> (b5, b5, b5, b5, b5)
```

Answer (score 4):

A tuple is a grouping of a specific number of values of (potentially) **different types**. Even if you consider the expression `(10,11,12,13,14)`, each element may have a different type:

```
Prelude> :t (10,11,12,13,14)
(10,11,12,13,14)
  :: (Num t, Num t1, Num t2, Num t3, Num t4) => (t4, t3, t2, t1, t)
```

For instance, the expression `10` may be an `Int`, while `11` may be a `Word`, and so on.

In general, you could also have written a five-tuple like `("foo", 42, True, "bar", 11)`, which has this type:

```
Prelude> :t ("foo", 42, True, "bar", 11)
("foo", 42, True, "bar", 11)
  :: (Num t, Num t1) => ([Char], t1, Bool, [Char], t)
```

The first element is a `[Char]` value (i.e. a `String`), the next element is some number, the third element is a `Bool`, and so on.

You can't apply the function `+3` to all of those elements. Even if you think it'd be meaningful for strings (which it isn't, IMO), I hope you agree that you can't add `3` to `True`.

Because of their types, tuples are generally not `Functor` instances, and therefore, you can't use `fmap` with them.

---

As Willem Van Onsem points out in the comments, a two-tuple *is* a `Functor`, but it may not behave in the way you expect. The [Haskell *pair* is a bit funky](https://youtu.be/87re_yIQMDw).

Comment: "Because of their types, tuples are generally not `Functor` instances" -- I wouldn't put it like that. While not everyone agrees on this, I'm firmly in the camp that finds the `Functor` instance for pairs perfectly reasonable. Instances for larger tuples targeting the last component would be just as reasonable; the base libraries don't provide them merely because, in practice, they are needed far less often than the pair one (and, accordingly, there have been suggestions to add the missing instances for the sake of consistency).

Comment: @duplode Indeed, but I do belong to the camp that find the `Functor` instance for `(,)` unintuitive. I do understand why it's there, but I find it implicit and arbitrary. Again, I understand that the reason the translation is applied to the second element is due to partial application, but I find that this is an implementation detail of the language, rather than a proper abstraction. To be clear, I find your comment valuable, and have also upvoted your answer, so it's not my intent to escalate the discussion at all, but I did want to make my position more explicit.

Comment: [1/2] That's fine. I acknowledge that is a rather controversial topic, and my answer was partly aimed at making the controversy explicit :) On "I find it implicit", I agree that it is often to be better to use `second` instead of `fmap @((,) _)` when writing concrete code. From a practical point of view, a better motivation for the `Functor` instance is its usefulness in abstract, functor-oriented code (think *lens* or *recursion-schemes*).

Comment: [2/2] On a related note, I find it nice that `fmap (+3) (Compose [(1,4),(2,0)])` -- or, to mention an even more vilified instance, `sum (Compose [(1,4),(2,0)])` -- do what we'd expect for a dictionary (that happens to have been implemented as an association list).